# Rails FileSystemResolver - Implementing custom template inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, template-engine, actionpack

If anyone has a better way of achieving the same desired affect, with a different structure, I'm perfectly happy abandoning this design.

My motivation here is to create an inherited javascript widget template system for use in Rails 3.  I want javascript widgets a user can place on their page and have a variety of pre-defined template that they can choose from.

Ideally, each template will have "base" javascript code, and any customizations can be layered on through a set of child templates (thus making a skin/new functionality for the template).

This is complicated in that I want to use multiple controllers for the same templates.

#### Controllers

Folder Tree

- app

  - controllers

    - widgets

      - modules
      - activities

        - content
        - images
      - communities

        - modules
        - activities

          - content
          - images
      - users

        - modules
        - activities

          - content
          - images

#### Views

Just a note on views, in each "template" directory, i've placed a file called config.rb.  This file defines a templates parent template name and folder location.  I'll show how this loads up in the template resolver.

Examples inheritance config files

**located in app/views/widgets/communities/modules/template_custom_2/config.rb**

```
module InheritedTemplateConfig
    def inherited_parent_base_path
        "widgets/communities/modules"
    end

    def inherited_parent_template_name
        "template_custom_1"
    end
end
```

**located in app/views/widgets/communities/modules/template_custom_1/config.rb**

```
module InheritedTemplateConfig
    def inherited_parent_base_path
        "widgets/communities/modules"
    end

    def inherited_parent_template_name
        "template"
    end
end
```

**located in app/views/widgets/communities/modules/template/config.rb**

```
module InheritedTemplateConfig
    def inherited_parent_base_path
        "widgets/communities"
    end

    def inherited_parent_template_name
        "template"
    end
end
```

Example template files

**located in app/views/widgets/communities/modules/template_custom_2/modules.js.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => "(TEMPLATE)/same_template_test" %>
<%= render :partial => "(PARENT_TEMPLATE)/parent_template_test" %>
```

Folder Tree

- app

  - views

    - widgets

      - modules

        - template
        - template_custom_1
        - template_custom_2
      - activities

        - template
        - content

          - template
        - images

          - template
      - communities

        - template
        - modules

          - template
          - template_custom_a
          - template_custom_b
        - activities

          - template
          - content

            - template
          - images

            - template
      - users

        - template
        - modules

          - template
        - activities

          - template
          - content

            - template
          - images

            - template

So, a few path examples and where I would expect the template chain of folders to resolve.

- /widgets/modules.js

  - /widgets/modules/template

  /widgets/communities/1/modules.js?template=custom_a

  - /widgets/communities/modules/template_custom_a
  - /widgets/communities/modules/template
  - /widgets/modules/template

#### My Failed Implementation

Just want to say, this is *so* close to working.  Unfortunately, I have had 0 luck in the resolvers (PARENT_TEMPLATE) find_template function case, it recurses infinitely.  This is because I have no way of knowing which template to skip when resolving.

The only thing that doesn't work is rendering a partial using `<% render :partial => "(PARENT_TEMPLATE)/my_file" %>`

```
class Widgets::Communities::ModulesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter do
        @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])

        @template = params[:template].to_s
        @template = "_#{@template}" if !@template.empty?

        # Path to start searching for template files
        prepend_view_path WidgetResolver.new("widgets/communities/modules", "template#{@template}")
    end

    def script
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render "modules" }
        end
    end
end


# Walks through from the sub_path to the base_path to find the template file
# This allows you to base one template on another template
class WigetResolver < ActionView::FileSystemResolver
    attr_accessor :templates, :base_path

    # Loads our current templates config, and any parent templates config
    def load_template_config(base_path, template_name)
        config_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{base_path}/#{template_name}/config.rb" 
        if File.exists?(config_path)
            self.templates << {:template_name => template_name, :base_path => base_path} # This is a valid template, add it to our search path
            load(config_path)
            extend InheritedTemplateConfig
            if !self.inherited_parent_base_path.nil? && !self.inherited_parent_template_name.nil?
                self.load_template_config(self.inherited_parent_base_path, self.inherited_parent_template_name)
            end
        end
    end
   def initialize(base_path, template_name)
        self.templates = []
        # From our base config, load our complete config
        self.load_template_config(base_path, template_name)
        super("app/views")
    end

    def find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)

        # We want to use our custom template matching
        if prefix.match(/^(TEMPLATE)/)
            self.templates.each_with_index { |template,i|
                result = super(name, "#{template[:base_path]}/#{template[:template_name]}", partial, details)

                # We found the custom template path
                return result if result.present?
            }
        # ----------------------------------------------------
        # ERROR HERE - recurses to max depth
        # ----------------------------------------------------
        elsif prefix.match(/^(PARENT_TEMPLATE)/)
            self.templates.each_with_index { |template,i|

                # We need to skip template above the current partials template file path - HOW DO WE DO THIS?!

                result = super(name, "#{template[:base_path]}/#{template[:template_name]}", partial, details)

                # We found the custom template path
                return result if result.present?
            }
        end

        super(name, prefix, partial, details)
    end

end
```

So - the question.  How can I know what the current partials working directory is in find_templates?  If I knew this, I could skip all templates above it, and never get the infinite recurse.